# Cancel a HTML onSubmit Event

Tags: javascript, html

So I've condensed my problem into a snippet of HTML code for you guys to try out on your own.

I believe this was working in Firefox 3.6 but in more recent releases it no longer seems to work. It also doesn't work in IE9 or Firefox Nightly.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function newEvent() {
        var myEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        myEvent.initEvent("click", false, false);
        getElementById('Test').dispatchEvent(myEvent);
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <form action="" onSubmit="newEvent();return false;">
      <input name="OK" type="submit" value="OK" />
      <input id="Test" name="Test" type="button" onClick="alert('Success!');" value="Test" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem I'm getting is that the form is being submit to the page, when I don't want it to be. I've tried "return false;", I've tried "event.preventDefault();". If you comment the dispatchEvent line, everything else works as expected. I'm lead to believe that for some reason dispatching a new event (the click) seems to allow the onSubmit event to continue.

You can test yourself by clicking "OK", which should fire onSubmit. Expected behaviour would be that a click event is generated for the "Test" button, then the onSubmit event is cancelled by the "return false;" section.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something in your code:

```
document.getElementById()
```

See the third line:

```
function newEvent() {
    var myEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    myEvent.initEvent("click", false, false);
    document.getElementById('Test').dispatchEvent(myEvent);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csrn5/2/

In `newEvent()`, the third line needs `document.`. So what's happening is you're getting an error and that error is stopping the JS before it gets to the `return false`.

Another way of demonstrating the problem:

```
function newEvent() {
    try {
        var myEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        myEvent.initEvent("click", false, false);
        getElementById('Test').dispatchEvent(myEvent);
    } catch(e){
        alert(e)
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csrn5/4/

Note, fix the error, I just wanted to show you that that was the actual problem.

Comment: Thanks Jared. You've certainly fixed the problem with the example that I've provided. Unfortunately that's not the problem with my original code, but I'll take a closer look and try to catch the error using the sample code you've given.